# Can I exclude a entity's property from binding a form in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm having a problem where I have a Company entity using doctrine and zend form annotations, so whenever I try to add a new Company it is invalid, checking the messages it tells me that 'active', which is a required field, is empty or null in my form, and this is because I have set this in my db with a default 1 value. So my question is, is there a way to ignore 'active' property to bind and validate against my form?

this is my add action

```
public function addAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $company = new Company();

    $entityManager = $this->entityManager();
    $builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
    $form = $builder->createForm($company);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()){
        $form->bind($company);
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()){
            print_r($form->getData());exit;
        } 
        print_r($form->getMessages());
    }
    $view->form = $form;
    return $view;
}
```

And this is my entity

```
namespace Nomina\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 * @Annotation\Name("CompanyForm")
 */
class Company
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Company name: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"NotEmpty","options":{"messages":{"isEmpty":"Empresa no puede ser vacio"}}})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rfc", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"RFC: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 */
private $rfc;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Street: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 */
private $street;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="City", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"City: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Number: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 */
private $number;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Phone: "})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $active = '1';

/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Submit")
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"value":"Procesar"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"btn btn-primary"})
 */
public $submit;
```

and my add view

```
$title = 'Add Company';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<hr />
<?php
$form = $this->form;

$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('company', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('rfc'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('street'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('number'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('city'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('phone'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit'));

echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

And when I print the message I get after isValid y get this message

```
Array ( [active] => Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) )
```

Comment: I don't use the form annotations, but can't you just set `@Annotation\Required({"required":"false"})` on your `$active` property?

Comment: yeah I thought about that, but it is required in another form, an admin can edit a Company, which is the same form, but with the active field displayed, so it is a required field, in the db it should be either 1 or 0

Comment: ah, then probably best to set the validation group, and exclude that particular field -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your validation group in your action depending the circumstances

```
$form->setValidationGroup('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message');
$form->setData($data);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // Contains only the "name", "email", "subject", and "message" values
    $data = $form->getData();
}
```

Just in case you need to add a captcha: here is a complete example:

```
$entityManager = $this->entityManager();
$builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
$form = $builder->createForm($company);

$form->add(array(
    'name' => 'captcha',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
    'options' => array(
        'captcha' => new \Zend\Captcha\Figlet(array(
            'wordLen' => 3,
        )),
    ),
));

$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()){
    $form->bind($company);
    $form->setValidationGroup('captcha',...);
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
```

Remember: Any excluded field using setValidationGroup() will not be included in form data!

More info in official docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups